# Transition Function Not working with my group in gganimate

Tags: r, gganimate

I am trying to get two bar graphs where the position = "dodge" but it keeps stacking them when I don't want it to. All I want is for gganimate to to do transition_reveal where each of the bars comes up and I want the bars to be separate but it seems like I have to pick one over the other. In the example below, if I add group = Year into the aesthetics then it will stack the bars, but if I don't have it in there it gives me transition_reveal instead of transition_states

```
library(magrittr)
library(broom)
library(purrr)
library(gganimate)
library(gifski)
library(ggthemes)
library(png)
library(jpeg)
library(ggimage)
library(grid)

Description <- c("Cost", "Cost", "Cost", "Margin", "Margin", "Margin")
Dollars <- c(1000, 1000, 1500, 200, 200, 200)
Year <- c(2016, 2017, 2018, 2016, 2017, 2018)
             
             
example <- data.frame(Year, Description, Dollars)

example_bar <- ggplot(data = example)+
  geom_bar(
    mapping = aes(x = Year, y = Dollars, fill = Description), #where I would typically add group
    position = "dodge",
    stat = "identity")
example_bar

example_anim <- example_bar + transition_states(Year, wrap = FALSE) +
  shadow_mark()+
  enter_grow()+
  enter_fade()
example_anim
```

[image: Example without Group in aes]

Without group in the aes.

With group in aes

[image]

Comment: So you want to keep plot the same but change the animation?

Comment: I want the second animation where it grows, but have two different bars for the cost and the margin

Comment: What if you use `group = interaction(Year, Description)` instead of `group = Year`?

Comment: Brilliant, how did you come up with that? Is there some documentation to point to just for future reference?